# The space of triangles that fit inside a given triangle, parametrized by edge lengths

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, plane-geometry, polyhedra

Given a triangle *T* with sides *a, b,* and *c,* describe its "fitting set," the set of all points (*x,y,z*) in 3-dimensions for which a triangle with sides *x, y, z* exists that fits in *T.*

Such a set lies in the positive octant, is star-shaped with respect to the origin, and probably is a polyhedron; but it seems difficult to describe.

Comment: Welcome to MO! I tried to make your title a bit more informative, hope that's all right.

Comment: This problem can be found in the book "100 problems" by Hugo Steinhaus, but without solution.

Comment: This space is not convex. Consider a triangle with sides $(1,1,2-\epsilon_1)$ for $0 < \epsilon_1 <1$. For small $\epsilon_2$, a triangle with sides $(1,1,\epsilon_2)$ will fit inside, but an equilateral triangle with sides $(1,1,1)$ will not. Another way to see failure of convexity is that if triangles of sides $(3/2,3/2,\epsilon), (3/2,\epsilon, 3/2), (\epsilon,3/2,3/2)$ fit, this does not imply an equilateral $(1,1,1)$ fits.

Comment: It seems the case of two right angled triangles has been considered in the literature, see J.H. Jepsen, V. Vulpe "Fitting One Right Triangle in Another" https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/jepsen6-200737759.pdf

Comment: @j.c. The isosceles triangle with legs of length $1$ and apex angle $30^\circ$ doesn't fit into the equilateral $(1,1,1)$.

Comment: @MTyson thanks, I wasn't thinking clearly.

Answer (score 17):

Here's the abstract of [K.A. Post, "Triangle in a triangle: On a problem of Steinhaus", Geom Dedicata (1993) 45: 115](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01667408); this paper was cited in the one given in the comment by Nemo.

> A necessary and sufficient condition on the sides $p, q, r$ of a triangle $PQR$ and the sides $a, b, c$ of a triangle $ABC$ in order that $ABC$ contains a congruent copy of $PQR$ is the following: At least one of the 18 inequalities obtained by cyclic permutation of $\{a, b, c\}$ and arbitrary permutation of $\{p, q, r\}$ in the formula:
>   \begin{array}{l} Max\{ F(q^2  + r^2  - p^2 ), F'(b^2  + c^2  - a^2 )\}  \\           +  Max\{ F(p^2  + r^2  - q^2 ), F'(a^2  + c^2  - b^2 )\}  \le 2Fcr \\  \end{array}
>   is satisfied. In this formula $F$ and $F'$ denote the surface areas of the triangles, i.e.
>   \begin{array}{l} F = {\textstyle{1 \over 4}}(2a^2 b^2  + 2b^2 c^2  + 2c^2 a^2  - a^4  - b^4  - c^4 )^{1/2}  \\  F' = {\textstyle{1 \over 4}}(2p^2 q^2  + 2q^2 r^2  + 2r^2 p^2  - p^4  - q^4  - r^4 )^{1/2} . \\  \end{array}

Here's a picture for the case $a=b=c=1$, which I plotted in [this SageMath Jupyter notebook](https://github.com/jcmathoverflow/jc-MO-nb/blob/master/posttriangle.ipynb).  Note that in this case we need only consider 3 of the above inequalities (plus the triangle inequalities):

[image: region for equilateral triangle]